# Powerpoint dateadd/date change subtraction

Tags: vba, date, powerpoint, dateadd

I have a variable (rptdate) that the user enters.  I want to create a another variable (startdate) that is 7 days earler than the rptdate.

*I plan on using enddate also so that has been created below in addition to the other variables

```
Dim rptdate As Variant
Dim StartDate As Variant
Dim enddate As Variant

rptdate = InputBox("enter report date")
enddate = Format(rptdate, "mmmm d,yyyy")
StartDate = DateAdd(D, -7, enddate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An InputBox always returns text, so try this:

```vb
Dim rptInput  As String
Dim rptDate   As Date
Dim StartDate As String
Dim EndDate   As String

rptInput = InputBox("Enter report date")

If IsDate(rptInput) Then
    rptDate = DateValue(rptInput)
    EndDate = Format(rptDate, "mmmm d, yyyy")
    StartDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -7, rptDate), "mmmm d, yyyy")
End If
```